# Failed to load codeclimate report, but report exists

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-climate, phpstan

in gitlab, I have a pipeline which generate a code climate report, supposed to be displayed in the gitlab widget.

The report is successfully generated (I added `cat code-quality.json` but I have the message «Failed to load codeclimate report».

When I check the source code of the gitlab page, I see a string which seems to contains the code responsible of the problem:

```
window.gl.mrWidgetData = { … ,"codeclimate":{"head_path":"/needhelp/needhelp-web/-/jobs/123456789/artifacts/download?file_type=codequality\u0026proxy=true","base_path":"/needhelp/needhelp-web/-/jobs/987654321/artifacts/download?file_type=codequality\u0026proxy=true"},"…
```

When I copy/paste the path in my url bar without the `\u0026proxy=true`, the file is successfully downloaded.

Here the `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration which generate the file.

```
static analysis:
    stage: test
    interruptible: true
    image:
        name: $CI_QA_IMAGE
        entrypoint: [""]
    script:
        - composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --classmap-authoritative --quiet
        - php bin/console --env=test cache:warmup
        - |
            ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyze -c phpstan.neon --no-progress --memory-limit 1G --error-format=gitlab > code-quality.json && phpstan_error=0 || phpstan_error=1
            if [[ -n $phpstan_error ]]; then
                echo -e '\e[103;1mphpstan detected errors.\e[0m'
                ls -lh code-quality.json
                cat code-quality.json
                ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyze -c phpstan.ci.neon --no-progress --memory-limit 1G
            else
                echo -e '\e[92;1mphpstan detected no error with levelmax configuration.\e[0m'
            fi
        - bin/console lint:twig --env=test
        - bin/console lint:container --env=test
        - bin/console lint:xliff translations/ --env=test
    artifacts:
        when: always
        reports:
            codequality: ./code-quality.json
```

Do you know what is wrong with this code ? Or if it's ok, where should I look to fix this ?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html#no-code-quality-report-is-displayed-in-a-merge-request

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is gitlab failed to parse `code-quality.json`
You can use some tool to validate the json format, for example: http://json.parser.online.fr/